# get confidence level in C# using ABBYY FlexiCapture SDK

Tags: abbyy

i am using abbyy flexi capture sdk to read data from an image. everything else is working fine. now i need to read confidence level that how accurately image is read. can anyone tell me how can i do this in C#? abbyy flexicapture sdk provide any functionality like this or not?

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use the `.xml` export setting with "Character Recognition Quality Info" enabled.
[image: Character Recognition Quality Info]

Answer (score -1):

To be able to get the confidence of the words please try to use RecognizedWordInfo::WordConfidence – this property returns the value of recognition confidence for the current variant of word recognition. More information please find in Help → API Reference → Objects → Text-Related Objects → RecognizedWordInfo.

To be able to get the confidence of the character please try to use RecognizedCharacterInfo::CharConfidence – this property stores the value of recognition confidence for current variant of character recognition. More information please find in Help → API Reference → Objects → Text-Related Objects → RecognizedCharacterInfo.

Also you could specify the confidence level at which a character in recognized text is marked as uncertainly recognized. For this please try to use TextRecognitionParams::ErrorHighlightLevel. More information in Help → API Reference → Objects → Document Definition Structure → Processing Parameters  → TextRecognitionParams.

If you need help in future, you can use [ABBYY OCR SDK Forum](http://forum.ocrsdk.com) to get an answer faster than at stackoverflow